# External API fetch() failure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am learning how to use the fetch() API in JavaScript. Right now i am trying to convert some code i have that is using curl to request data from an external API (aviationstack.com) in my php, and replace it by AJAX calls. I am using their free plan, which doesn't support https, and hence i am trying to fetch from their API using a http URL :

```js
fetch('http://api.aviationstack.com/v1/flights?access_key=myaccesskey').then(function(response) 
{
    //some stuff here
});
```

This same url works fine with curl in my php code. Issue is the API seems to receive this call as https, since it returns me this json :

```json
{"error":{"code":"https_access_restricted","message":"Access Restricted - Your current Subscription Plan does not support HTTPS Encryption."}}
```

Does anyone know what could cause this ? I'm scratching my head over it, and i can't get it to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated, as i don't fully understand this process and i would be glad to get a better understanding of it.

EDIT : It seems i am truly an idiot. This was a network issue all along... Thanks for the answers, much appreciated

Comment: Maybe the API is redirecting all calls made to HTTP to HTTPS. Are you sure the same protocol is used when using Curl?

Comment: I am not quite sure, no . It could be that, since using `file_get_contents()` in php fails as well. I do not know enough about curl and fetch() mechanisms to really know.

Comment: What's the output when you try a ``curl -X GET 'http://api.aviationstack.com/v1/flights?access_key=myaccesskey'``?

Comment: The JSON is returned when doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Tried the same using my API key (on my local machine) :

```
fetch('http://api.aviationstack.com/v1/flights?access_key=<MY API KEY>').then(function(response) 
{
    console.log(response);
});
```

The console gives the desired response and I get 200 as status. Maybe you should check the API key.

Can you check/provide the **Request URL**?

Comment: API key is working, since curl returns me the data, or just writing the request in the browser directly works as well... Could it be something to do with CORS ? When inspecting the error i see this :

"Version HTTP/3;  Transferred 1.03 KB (142 B size); Referrer Policy strict-origin-when-cross-origin"

Comment: Can you use your network tab and post the request url here ?